# SharePoint Online, create application

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, console-application, sharepoint-online

I am testing to create custom application for SharePoint Online. This application just read the Title from sharepoint web. ( I use simple example from documentation)
I registered one with Azure Active Directory and gave **Applications** and **Delegated** permissions:

- Microsoft Graph - > Sites.Manage.All;
- SharePoint - > Sites.Manage.All

Also, I use PnP.Framework.  My target framework is .NET 6 and I'm using
Visual Studio 2022.

My code:

```cs
using PnP.Core.Auth;
using PnP.Core.Auth.Services.Builder.Configuration;
using PnP.Framework;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var scopes = new string[] { "https://***.sharepoint.com/.default" };
string clientId = "********-****-****-****-************";
string siteUrl = "https://***.sharepoint.com/";
string clientSecret = "********-****-****-****-************";


using (var cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl,clientId, clientSecret))
{
   cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
   cc.ExecuteQuery();
   Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
};
```

If I can trust the documentation it's  enough for this simple task.
But I have exception: "System.Exception: 'Token request failed.'"

> System.Exception   HResult=0x80131500   Message=Token request failed.
> Source=PnP.Framework   StackTrace:    at
> SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String
> securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)    at
> PnP.Framework.Utilities.TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(String
> targetPrincipalName, String targetHost, String targetRealm)    at
> PnP.Framework.Utilities.ACSTokenGenerator.GetToken(Uri siteUrl)    at
> PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager.<>c__DisplayClass75_0.b__0(Object
> sender, WebRequestEventArgs args)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.SetupServerQuery(ChunkStringBuilder
> sb)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder
> sb)    at ConsoleApp3.Program.d__0.MoveNext() in
> C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line
> 39
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: [External Code]
> Inner Exception 1:
> WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Any ideas what else I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the application must be using `TLS 1.2`  , as this error The remote server returned an error can occur due to `deprecation of TLS1 1.0 & 1.1` if they are in use.

For that please make sure  server supports one of supported cyphers:

```
1.  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
2.  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
3.  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA38
4.  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

**Note:** Azure ACS authentication may be  deprecated soon- and may result in such errors when in use.

- You can add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` to your code before you get the AppOnly
  access token .

**References:**

1. [no longer able to use  PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext · GitHub](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/issues/336)
2. [development - 400 Bad request](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235594/400-bad-request-when-loading-sharepoint-site-from-client)  /   [development - Error "Token request failed" when connecting to SharePoint site via PnP.Framework - SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/301173/error-token-request-failed-when-connecting-to-sharepoint-site-via-pnp-framewor)

Comment: Thanks @kavya Saraboju, it was useful but not working for me. I checked that: TLS and supported cyphers were all right.